# EasyPost integration with Exp:resso Store

Tags: expresso-store, module, shipping

Has anyone tried integrating [EasyPost](https://www.easypost.com) with Exp:resso Store? They seem like a good fit, and I might have a go at it myself if necessary, but I don't want to duplicate anybody's work.

Alternately, is there a basic template for a Store shipping module that I can start from?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anyone that has implemented EasyPost with Store. Store's shipping gateways are undergoing a major overhaul in how they function from v1 to v2 (which is under active development now). Depending on your timeframe I would recommend waiting for v2 to be released (or emailing support@exp-resso.com to see about getting added in to the beta).

There is not an example shipping module per say but you can look at the UPS/USPS/FedEx plugins in the current version of Store to see how things are setup currently as a great starting point. In v2 the shipping plugins are handled as extensions which should make them easier to create and extend.